# How do I get brightness controls working on a Dell XPS m1710?

Tags: brightness, backlight

I've been reading on for a while now on how to resolve the issue of my backlight not working.  I'm using  Dell xps m1710 and my Fn arrow keys are able to control the brightness slider but the actual brightness doesn't change.

I've tried many different things so far and the only things that shows any progress is typing xbacklight = 10  into my terminal which only gets me a flash of what i'd hope my screen looked like right now.  Any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with another Linux distribution and fixed it by blacklisting nouveau driver and installing nvidia driver